# Update only one column in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Would like to update the first column of a table while leaving the data of the other columns.

Example:

```
Pet     Count
==============
Cat       4
Dog       1
Hamster   9
```

Update with this table:

```
Pet
===
Cat
Hamster
Monkey
```

Desired result:

```
Pet    count
============
Cat      4
Hamster  9
Monkey
```

As you can see Dog fell out because it was not in the second table. Monkey was added with a blank count.

I though it was Update query but. Reading about update query it looks like they are only used for find and replace.

Comment: Left Join the second table to the first table.

Comment: You can create a query that generates the result that you want (see my answer below for the SQL code but you can do it very easily with the query GUI). If you want to actually modify the table itself you will have to fist use the query to create a new table, then delete the original table and rename the new table to what the original's name was.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Table2].Pet, [Table1].Count
FROM [Table2]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table1] ON [Table2].Pet=[Table1].Pet
```